# Не хватает фактических параметров для макроопределения "max"

Tags: c++, валидация

Имеется функция для валидации ввода:

```
void inputNumber(int &a) {
    while (true) {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.get() == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
    }
}
```

Однако подчеркивает `max()` и пишет, что

> не хватает фактических параметров для макроопределения "max"

. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, включили `windows.h`, а в нем есть макрос `max`...

Определите

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

перед

```
#include<windows.h>
```

Comment: Или напишите `(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max)()`